# How to add multiple instances of the native add UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps, ads, uwp-xaml

I have an UWP app which displays several catalogs of videos. They are located in separate pages. For this purpose I've created an `NativeAdV2` control:

```
public sealed partial class CardAdvert : UserControl
{
    NativeAdsManagerV2 manager = new NativeAdsManagerV2("d25517cb-12d4-4699-8bdc-52040c712cab", "test");
    NativeAdV2 advert;
    public CardAdvert()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        manager.AdReady += AdReady;
        manager.RequestAd();
    }

    private void AdReady(object sender, NativeAdReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        advert = e.NativeAd;
        Initialize();
        e.NativeAd.RegisterAdContainer(this);    //Exception is here
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        title.Text = advert.Title;
        image.Source = new BitmapImage(advert.MainImages.First().Url.ToUri());
        if (advert.AdIcon == null)
            contentGrid.ColumnDefinitions[0].Width = new GridLength(0);
        else
            icon.ProfilePicture = advert.AdIcon.Source;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(advert.SponsoredBy))
            sponsor.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        else
            sponsor.Text = advert.SponsoredBy;

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(advert.Rating))
            info.Text += $" {advert.Rating}";

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(advert.CallToActionText) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(advert.Price))
            desc.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(advert.CallToActionText))
            desc.Text = advert.CallToActionText;
        else
            desc.Text = advert.Price;
    }
}
```

But no matter where I create it (even on different page) on the second or third time it throws me an exception on `e.NativeAd.RegisterAdContainer(this)`:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x082A1330 (Windows.UI.Xaml.dll) in FoxTube.exe:
0xC000027B: An application-internal exception has occurred (parameters: 0x1E9F4608, 0x00000003)
```

There is no anything similar neither on MSDN forum or elsewhere nor in [NativeAdV2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/microsoft.advertising.winrt.ui.nativeadv2) class documentation

Perfectly, I'd like to insert this control every 10 videos. Or at least on every page. Is there any solutions?

Comment: Error reporting like this requires a crystal ball.  Error code 3 generally means "Path not found".  Which suggests that *this* is no longer valid.  Which suggests that you can't ignore NativeAdsManagerV2.Dispose().

Comment: @HansPassant, Yeah. I thought about `Dispose` method but how to implement this? I've tried to put `RegisterAdContainer` into a `try/catch` block and dispose and reload the ad if it throw an exception. But it just ignores block and crashes my app anyway. Also I've tried dispose it every time before using and reloading it again. It shows the same result

Comment: @HansPassant, I've created the sample to show this issue and how I deliver the ads https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnQ5WkWqz7MKi9Vc62Nj78nmCIrr-g

Comment: Please pay attention to the thread of your post in MSDN, I will update there, if I get the solution from the consultation.

Comment: @DasiyTianMSFT, is there any other solution to this issue? Because I can't downgrade the Target Version to 16299.

Comment: @DasiyTianMSFT, nope. It still doesn't work in latest versions. But that's not that bad. You can use [Windows UI Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/toolkits/winui/) if you want to use latest controls and features in your project. Plus, you shouldn't downgrade your target version so far. 17134 on Target and Minimal versions works perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I don't know why Microsoft doesn't want to fix this but as they said it works on earlier builds. You just need to downgrade your target and minimal versions to 17134 and it will work. You can also use [Windows UI Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/toolkits/winui/) to get latest XAML controls

Comment: Microsoft.UI.Xaml nuget package requires TargetPlatformVersion >= 10.0.17763.0

Comment: @ac-lap, this library is also have to be downgraded. I don't remember the right version, so try to downgrade it step by step until it matches. As I could see it affect only text default sizes